# Error when setting up virtualenv with Python 3

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm attempting to create a virtualenv (using virtualenvwrapper) with Python 3 as my default interpreter, but keep receiving the same error after un/reinstalling Python 3, virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper several times.

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 test-env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 23, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 405, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyString_AsString
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so
```

I have both Python 2 (prepackaged version for OS X) and Python 3 (via `brew install python3`) installed.

I can create virtualenvs fine using any of my Python 2 binaries.

Comment: Try adding the argument `--no-site-packages` -> `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 --no-site-packages test-env`

Comment: Seeing the exact same error unfortunately. I've attempted a few variations (`pyenv` installations and fussing with PYTHONPATH) to no avail...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've created an issue on virtualenv's GitHub repo: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/779.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error, and in my case I was able to solve it with the following steps:

```
$ brew unlink python3
$ brew link --overwrite python3
$ unset PYTHONPATH
```

After that, `virtualenv` worked as expected.